# Unable to generate signed apk in Android Studio, getting error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWith

Tags: android

I am generating a signed apk in android studio but I'm getting following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzp.class

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.jetserve.mocamandroid"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10000002
        versionName "1.000000b"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
}

dependencies {
    //HELP CENTER
    compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.11.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk-providers', version: '1.11.0.1'
    compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.8.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7';
        exclude module: 'support-v4';
        exclude module: 'design';
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }


    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
    compile project(':libwebrtc')
    compile project(':dialogLibrary')

    //WebRTC socket
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    //firebase
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    //bottom navigation bar in settings activity
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.3.3'

    //ripple effect
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

    //compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'

    //notification
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`3.1.0`** version.

```
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
```

If same problem coming then Remove

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not worked..
I could not try second solution because I should use 'FirebaseAuth'.

Comment: @OKMIN yes yes.

Comment: @OKMIN for test case use `11.4.2` instead of `11.6.0`.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: So I add     dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } in build.gradle file